# WordPress Shortcode converting lowercase 'x' between numbers to &#215;

Tags: wordpress

I have

`[shortcode]http://image-150x150.jpg[/shortcode]`

The `htmlentities()` output shows the `'x'` as × only if between two numbers.

```
So this [shortcode]150x 150X150 150x150 1x1 x1 X1[/shortcode] gives this
150x 150X150 150&#215;150 1&#215;1 x1 X1
```

So the issue is, that isn't an x.  So for image file names image-150x150.jpg, won't work in the html.  It isn't an x - it is something different.  Doesn't happen with Uppercase X.  Just lowercase, and only between two numbers.

Thus if your shortcode code is something like

```
function add_shortcode_bs_modal($atts, $content = null) {
    return '<img scr="'.$content.'" />;
}
```

And the `$content is = to http://image-150x150.jpg` - the link won't work.  Because the x is converted to something else, this × thing.

Comment: Wp is changing the x between two numbers because assume is a multiplication, see this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize I guess you need to return the $content without that filter, you can try with: $unfiltered_content = get_the_content(); then use that.

Comment: Up vote the comment please :)

Comment: I can't upvote comment for some reason.

Comment: @rgdesign Better to post your comment as an _answer_ so the OP can _accept_ it.